# Error calling filename from csvread in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, matlab-guide

I've been using matlab to analyise and work through a decission tree to give a True/False answer back.

I wanted to add more functionality to allow the user to either read data from a csv file or manually enter the data. I'm currently getting the error below, i've tried using this csv method on previous data and it works fine. (I'm aware the user input does nothing at the moment havent added functionality yet)

Error in csvread (line 47)
 m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);

Error in second_draft (line 28)
M = csvread(filename, 1)

I tried using dlmread but also got an error, some numbers in the csv are floating point and some are integers i'm not sure if that is anything to do with the error.

data im trying to read looks like the below

[Image of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMqm1.png)

```
prompt = input('Do you want to manually input values or select file? :','s'); %user prompt to select manual data entry or to read csv file


s2 = {'file','folder';           %array of strings that will be compared against user input 
      'f','choose'};

tf = strcmp(prompt,s2);          % string compare of user input 'prompt' against array 's2'

if any(tf(:))                    %tf(:) returns a column vector of all elements in tf, and any() checks if there are any values greater than 1.


[filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.csv'}, 'File selector')


else        
        prompt = {'Enter matrix size:','Enter colormap name:',};
        dlg_title = 'Input';
        num_lines = 1;
        defaultans = {'20','hsv'};
        answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);  

end

for x = 1:267


M = csvread(filename, 1);


val1=M(x,1);
val3=M(x,3);
val7=M(x,7);
val8=M(x,8);
val9=M(x,9);
val10=M(x,10);
val11=M(x,11);
val12=M(x,12);
val13=M(x,13);

outcome = [];


if val3 <= 3
    if val13 <= 3
        if val10 <=1.6
            outcome = 'False';
        else
```

Obviously there is more code to run through the entire decision tree, i've tested it standalone and it works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I've tried everything I know and can't solve it!

Comment: look at your brackets: `M = csvread(filename, 1)`. Is that how you have in your file?

Comment: Yes jsut have a ; on the end to suppress it in the command window.

Comment: No, in you code you have typed: `M = csvread(filename, 1]` have a look at the end bracket.

Comment: apologies its a ) bracket in my script

Comment: The documentation for `csvread` and `dlmread` clearly state they can only be used for *numeric* data. You are passing mixed data because `Result` is a string. Use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)